# how to connect reverse proxy Server

Tags: iis, reverse-proxy, switch, ethernet

I have an IIS-ARR LoadBalancing server connected to internet. And I have 2 IIS web servers in a LAN (using a switch) without internet. The IIS-ARR is configured as reverse proxy for 2 websites [www.website1.com](http://www.website1.com) and [www.website2.com](http://www.website2.com).  These 2 websites are deployed on the 2 IIS webservers in LAN.

1. How do I connect the IIS-ARR server and the 2 Webservers in LAN? I mean do I need 2 NICs for the IIS-ARR reverse proxy? One for internet and other for LAN?

Comment: Off topic: Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they attract low quality, opinionated and spam answers, and the answers become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe the business problem you are working on, the research you have done, and the steps taken so far to solve it. Also, this is a Q&A site - not a "multiple questions because reason". Split them offi.

Comment: My query is, is it fine if just reverse proxy server has internet and the servers behind it are in LAN without internet?

Comment: No, you have 4 questions. I am not sure how you count, but I count 4. You even number them. Also most questions are "teach me basics", and without relevant information - what CABLE? SERIOUSLY? Per site rules this is a plce for professionals.

Comment: Sorry for that, I have modified my query. My intention was to convey my query clearly.

Comment: Not sure which universe you modified the query in. I STILL see 4 questions. All, btw., broken neglish as they are clearly questions - but not ending in a "?".

Comment: Sorry if I bother you with many questions, I have made it simpler now.

Comment: @TomTom please clarify if possible.

Comment: Descriptions like "I have an IIS-ARR LoadBalancing server connected to internet" are too vague for discussions on networking. Learn the network for your servers, and then draw a good enough diagram to illustrate the devices involved (like [this one](https://blog.lextudio.com/self-hosting-series-why-cannot-my-web-server-iis-be-reached-from-anywhere-else-8da0e0b252ef)). Only then people can give you answers or advice.

Comment: @LexLi thanks for the link. I have already hosted my website over internet without load balancing. Now trying to move to live environment with load balancing. As I am not a networking guy, trying to get an idea about the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need two NICs if you have a good firewall/router. IIS-ARR should be in DMZ, while webservers are on LAN. With appropriate firewall rules to allow traffic between the two. [pfSense](https://pfsense.org) is an excellent open source firewall/router.

Comment: Iam not going to use firewall or router. I am going to plugin the internet cable directly to the IIS-ARR server. Is it possible this way and add another NIC to connect to LAN?

Comment: Thanks for DMZ info, it makes sense and serves my purpose from security front.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing this. Most people would just use their switches and existing network, but if you don't have one, you could use just cables.

ARR just has to be able to connecto to the target sites; how this is done, is completely up to you.

Comment: OK. So what I understand is it is possible without a firewall or router, instead adding another NIC to the IIS-ARR server.

Comment: Yes, you can add as many NICs as you need. As long as the ARR hosts can reach the destinations, it doesn't matter how.

Comment: Thanks for the Confirmation.